# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to pick up specific logback configuration

Tags: java, spring, junit

Is there any way to specify the logback configuration file to use in a JUnit run by Spring?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/my/app/springConfiguration.xml")
public class MyTest {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTest.class);

  @Autowired
  Something something;
}
```

Now, I have got *logback.xml* and multiple of them. There is one that is supposed to run in prod and then there is one that I want this test to pick up. Is there a easy way to do it?

---

Edit : This question is specific to the case when I am running the JUnit from my Eclipse. I am working on Eclipse 4.3 on windows 7.

---

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: Put the one for your tests in `src/test/resources` the production one in `src/main/resources`. You can also name your test config `logback-test.xml` that should also be picked up by logback.

Comment: Ok. But how would Spring know which one to pick up when. I wanted to see if there is someway I could actually force it to pick up one over another. E.g. like @ContextConfiguration is there something else which tells the JUnit to pick up a particular logback configuration?

Comment: JUnit is not aware of Logback so you cannot tell it to choose which logback configuration to use, as suggested by @M.Deinum, you should work on your classpath resources : src/test vs. src/main, or logback-test.xml vs. logback.xml, see [Configuration in logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration) for more details on logback configuration loading

Comment: The spring runner does something weird and doesn't add your test resources to the classpath or something...it's very odd

Answer (score 1):

Pass the location as a JVM argurment on the configuration that runs your tests in eclipse.

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile="fullpathtofile\logback.xml"
```